# how to run Jhipster Gateway app webapp:build

Tags: java, maven, npm, eslint, jhipster

I have a jhipster gateway generated app which I did not change anything with, I just wanted to start it, I did the following: mvn clean install -DskipTests, but it stops at the step of npm webapp:build I am getting right now the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (webapp build dev) on project moniesta: Failed to run task: 'npm run webapp:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

And the reason seems to be this:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '../.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
[INFO] Require stack:
[INFO] - /home/hasan/Desktop/Moniesta/Microservices/__placeholder__.js
[INFO] Referenced from: /home/hasan/Desktop/Moniesta/Microservices/.eslintrc.json
```

But I controlled my eslint and package json and everything seems to be alright. Could someone from you guys look at it, like I said I did not change anything from its default config/code:

eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "eslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
      "error",
      {
        "type": "element",
        "prefix": "jhi",
        "style": "kebab-case"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
      "error",
      {
        "type": "attribute",
        "prefix": "jhi",
        "style": "camelCase"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/relative-url-prefix": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "extendDefaults": true,
        "types": {
          "{}": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error", { "allowExpressions": true }],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
      "error",
      {
        "default": [
          "public-static-field",
          "protected-static-field",
          "private-static-field",
          "public-instance-field",
          "protected-instance-field",
          "private-instance-field",
          "constructor",
          "public-static-method",
          "protected-static-method",
          "private-static-method",
          "public-instance-method",
          "protected-instance-method",
          "private-instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-parameter-properties": ["warn", { "allows": ["public", "private", "protected"] }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-optional-chain": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": "off",
    "arrow-body-style": "error",
    "curly": "error",
    "eqeqeq": ["error", "always", { "null": "ignore" }],
    "guard-for-in": "error",
    "no-bitwise": "error",
    "no-caller": "error",
    "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
    "no-eval": "error",
    "no-labels": "error",
    "no-new": "error",
    "no-new-wrappers": "error",
    "object-shorthand": ["error", "always", { "avoidExplicitReturnArrows": true }],
    "radix": "error",
    "spaced-comment": ["warn", "always"]
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "moniesta",
  "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Description for moniesta",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "app:start": "./mvnw",
    "backend:build-cache": "./mvnw dependency:go-offline",
    "backend:debug": "./mvnw -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=\"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000\"",
    "backend:doc:test": "./mvnw -ntp javadoc:javadoc --batch-mode",
    "backend:info": "./mvnw -ntp enforcer:display-info --batch-mode",
    "backend:nohttp:test": "./mvnw -ntp checkstyle:check --batch-mode",
    "backend:start": "./mvnw -Dskip.installnodenpm -Dskip.npm",
    "backend:unit:test": "./mvnw -ntp -Dskip.installnodenpm -Dskip.npm verify --batch-mode -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.com.moniesta.gateway=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF",
    "build": "npm run webapp:prod --",
    "build-watch": "concurrently 'npm run webapp:build:dev -- --watch' npm:backend:start",
    "ci:backend:test": "npm run backend:info && npm run backend:doc:test && npm run backend:nohttp:test && npm run backend:unit:test -- -P$npm_package_config_default_environment",
    "ci:e2e:package": "npm run java:$npm_package_config_packaging:$npm_package_config_default_environment -- -Pe2e -Denforcer.skip=true",
    "ci:e2e:prepare": "npm run ci:e2e:prepare:docker",
    "ci:e2e:prepare:docker": "npm run docker:db:up && npm run docker:others:up && docker ps -a",
    "preci:e2e:server:start": "npm run docker:db:await --if-present && npm run docker:others:await --if-present",
    "ci:e2e:server:start": "java -jar target/e2e.$npm_package_config_packaging --spring.profiles.active=e2e,$npm_package_config_default_environment -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.com.moniesta.gateway=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF --logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR",
    "ci:e2e:teardown": "npm run ci:e2e:teardown:docker",
    "ci:e2e:teardown:docker": "npm run docker:db:down --if-present && npm run docker:others:down && docker ps -a",
    "ci:frontend:build": "npm run webapp:build:$npm_package_config_default_environment",
    "ci:frontend:test": "npm run ci:frontend:build && npm test",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/classes/static/",
    "docker:app:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d",
    "docker:db:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml down -v",
    "docker:db:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up -d",
    "docker:jhipster-registry:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml down -v",
    "docker:jhipster-registry:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml up -d",
    "docker:others:await": "echo \"Waiting for jhipster-registry to start\" && wait-on -t 180000 http-get://localhost:8761/management/health && echo \"jhipster-registry started\"",
    "docker:others:down": "npm run docker:jhipster-registry:down",
    "predocker:others:up": "",
    "docker:others:up": "npm run docker:jhipster-registry:up",
    "java:docker": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests -Pprod jib:dockerBuild",
    "java:docker:arm64": "npm run java:docker -- -Djib-maven-plugin.architecture=arm64",
    "java:docker:dev": "npm run java:docker -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:docker:prod": "npm run java:docker -- -Pprod",
    "java:jar": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests --batch-mode",
    "java:jar:dev": "npm run java:jar -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:jar:prod": "npm run java:jar -- -Pprod",
    "java:war": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests --batch-mode -Pwar",
    "java:war:dev": "npm run java:war -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:war:prod": "npm run java:war -- -Pprod",
    "jest": "jest --coverage --logHeapUsage --maxWorkers=2 --config jest.conf.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check \"{,src/**/,webpack/}*.{md,json,yml,html,cjs,mjs,js,ts,tsx,css,scss,java}\"",
    "prettier:format": "prettier --write \"{,src/**/,webpack/}*.{md,json,yml,html,cjs,mjs,js,ts,tsx,css,scss,java}\"",
    "serve": "npm run start --",
    "start": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start-tls": "npm run webapp:dev-ssl",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "ng test --coverage --log-heap-usage -w=2",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "watch": "concurrently npm:start npm:backend:start",
    "webapp:build": "npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:dev",
    "webapp:build:dev": "ng build --configuration development",
    "webapp:build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "webapp:dev": "ng serve",
    "webapp:dev-ssl": "ng serve --ssl",
    "webapp:dev-verbose": "ng serve --verbose",
    "webapp:prod": "npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:prod",
    "webapp:test": "npm run test --"
  },
  "config": {
    "backend_port": 8080,
    "default_environment": "prod",
    "packaging": "jar"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/localize": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "12.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
    "dayjs": "1.11.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "13.0.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "9.0.0",
    "rxjs": "7.5.5",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-builders/jest": "13.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "13.3.1",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "16.11.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.18.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.27.9",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "concurrently": "7.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "10.2.4",
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "3.1.1",
    "folder-hash": "4.0.2",
    "generator-jhipster": "7.8.1",
    "husky": "7.0.4",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-date-mock": "1.0.8",
    "jest-junit": "13.1.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "11.1.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "12.3.7",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.6.1",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.2.17",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "4.10.3",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "typescript": "4.6.3",
    "wait-on": "6.0.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.5.0",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.15.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.14.0"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results-sonar.xml"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "webpack": "5.71.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: standalone it is possible if I do it like this: npm run webapp:build

Comment: It seems you did not run `npm install` so some node modules are missing. Did you read your project's README.md and the official docs? https://www.jhipster.tech/development/

Comment: I did run npm install it is run automatically as well in generation time. But still I am gettting the same error

Comment: The npm build executed by maven frontend build is different from what you are doing in the sense that it does use its own node and npm versions as specified in pom.xml rather than your own installation. Have you compared your local node and npm versions versus the ons specified in pom.xml? Does it fail also if you don't skip tests?

Comment: hey that was the problem. My system had npm version 8.7.0 and mvn was on 8.6.0 used the later one now it worked also adjusted node versions

Answer (score 0):

If you have M1 Mac and you're using a node or webpack version in your tasks that required Rosetta, installing it will fix the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33891994)